# How to fetch only first two characters from my json value using regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to fetch the values from json string(due to some limitations I can't use the json library) so I am using the regex to extract the data from json string. I am able to fetch the complete value for the given match but as per my requirement I want to fetch first n characters from the value.

My Json String:

```
{
  "description":"descriptionTest",
  "TestName":"testNameValue",
  "sourceDisk":"instancsourcedisk",
  "status":"READY",
  "testNumber":123456,
  "testNumber1":334,
  "testNumber3":3,
}
```

Out put:

```
Regex: "testNumber1":"*(?<test>[^"]+(?="?\s*,))
matchValue: 334 
Regex: "sourceDisk":"*(?<test>[^"]+(?="?\s*,))
matchValue:instancsourcedisk
```

No issue with the full value, but when I am trying to get the first n characters it is not working .

I have tried another way also to get first n characters:

```
Regex: "sourceDisk":"*(?<test>[^"]{2})
value : in
Regex : "testNumber1":"*(?<test>[^"]{2})
value : 33
Regex : "testNumber3":"*(?<test>[^"]{2})
value: 3,
```

**in the above example when I have only single char in my value it is giving comma also**,

Please help me on it.

Comment: You want the first 2 characters, and the `,` is the second character. Do you want it not to match at all, or to return fewer characters?

Comment: Use `[^",]{1,2}` to match 1 or 2 characters, and not include quote or commas.

Comment: But what should happen if you have something like `"testNumber3":",123"`? Now the comma is inside the string, do you want to return it or not? This is why regular expressions aren't really powerful enough to parse JSON.

Comment: _"I am using the regex"_ - Ok, what tool or programming language are you using the regex in?

Comment: @Barmar [^",]{1,2} worked for me, Thank you for the quick help